# how to debug the sem_wait function in gdb?

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb, semaphore

I want to use gdb to debug multiple threads. Of course the threads use the semaphore to work together well. But when there is a sentence like:

```
sem_wait(&empty);
```

Assume now the semaphore empty should wait until the empty is available. In other words, it should block here. And the gdb is scheduler-locking on:

```
(gdb) show scheduler-locking 
      Mode for locking scheduler during execution is "on".
```

And then I input

```
n
```

the gdb is block like below. (Of course it should be block. But I want to go back to the command line to switch to other thread to continue debug.)

```
(gdb) n
^C
Thread 3 "sem" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7bc6f96 in futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=0, 
abstime=0x0, expected=0, futex_word=0x555555755060 <full>)
   at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:205
```

I want to use Ctrl-C, but the thread exits. So what should I do? Thanks for answers.

Comment: not quite sure what you're asking, but you can configure `gdb` to catch signals or pass them through to your code. If that's what you're asking, take a look here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html

Comment: @yano I explain the question. I don't think is the signal problem. Since it is running right, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use Ctrl-C, but the thread exits.

When your thread receives `SIGINT` signal, `sem_wait` should return with `EINTR` error. See [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html):

> EINTR  The call was interrupted by a signal handler; see signal(7).

You can try to add error handling of `EINTR` and call `sem_wait` again in case of this error to make your code more debuggable. You can use the wrapper for `sem_wait` from this [blog post](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-make-sem_t-interrupt-safe/):

```
static inline
int sem_wait_nointr(sem_t *sem) {
  while (sem_wait(sem))
    if (errno == EINTR) errno = 0;
    else return -1;
  return 0;
}
```